# Can a Standard ML functor take another functor as parameter?

Tags: sml, functor, ml

I have an implementation of sets and maps as unbalanced binary trees. Because sets and maps are so alike, I actually only wrote an implementation for maps from scratch, and then trivially implemented sets as maps from keys to units:

```
signature EQ =
sig
  type t;

  val eq : t * t -> bool;
end;

signature ORD =
sig
  include EQ;

  val lt : t * t -> bool;
end;

signature SET =
sig
  structure Elem : EQ;
  type      set;

  val empty  : set;
  val member : Elem.t * set -> bool;
  val insert : Elem.t * set -> set option;
end;

signature MAP =
sig
  structure Key : EQ;
  type      'a map;

  val empty  : 'a map;
  val lookup : Key.t      * 'a map -> 'a option;
  val insert : Key.t * 'a * 'a map -> 'a map option;
end;

functor UnbalancedMap (Key : ORD) :> MAP =
struct
  structure Key     = Key;
  datatype  'a tree = E | T of Key.t * 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;
  type      'a map  = 'a tree;

  val empty = E;

  fun lookup (k, t) =
    let
      fun loop (k, E, E) = NONE
        | loop (k, E, T (x, y, _, _)) =
          if Key.eq (k, x) then SOME y
                           else NONE
        | loop (k, t as T (x, _, a, b), r) =
          if Key.lt (k, x) then loop (k, a, r)
                           else loop (k, b, t);
    in
      loop (k, t, E)
    end;

  fun insert (k, v, t) =
    let
      exception Exists;

      fun loop (k, v, E, E) = T (k, v, E, E)
        | loop (k, v, E, T (x, _, _, _)) =
          if Key.eq (k, x) then raise Exists
                           else T (k, v, E, E)
        | loop (k, v, t as T (x, y, a, b), r) =
          if Key.lt (k, x) then T (x, y, loop (k, v, a, r), b)
                           else T (x, y, a, loop (k, v, b, t));
    in
      SOME (loop (k, v, t, E)) handle Exists => NONE
    end;
end;

functor UnbalancedSet (Elem : ORD) :> SET =
struct
  structure Map  = UnbalancedMap (Elem);
  structure Elem = Map.Key;
  type      set  = unit Map.map;

  val empty = Map.empty;

  fun member (x, t) = case Map.lookup (x, t) of
      NONE => false 
    | _    => true;

  fun insert (x, t) = Map.insert (x, (), t);
end;
```

Let's assume I come up with another implementation of maps using some other data structure. Then I should be able to reuse that data structure to define sets as maps from keys to units as well:

```
functor AnotherMap (Key : EQ) :> MAP =
struct
  (* ... *)
end;

functor AnotherSet (Elem : EQ) :> SET =
struct
  structure Map  = AnotherMap (Elem);
  structure Elem = Map.Key;
  type      set  = unit Map.map;

  val empty = Map.empty;

  fun member (x, t) = case Map.lookup (x, t) of
      NONE => false 
    | _    => true;

  fun insert (x, t) = Map.insert (x, (), t);
end;
```

However, if I come up with arbitrarily many implementations of maps, redefining sets that use the same data structures as those maps quickly becomes tedious. What I would really like to have is a functor that takes a functor from X to MAP, and produces a functor from X to SET, where X is any signature that includes EQ (or possibly EQ itself). Is this possible in Standard ML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a non-standard extension, yes.  I believe the feature you are looking for is called 'higher order functors' by SML/NJ.  Here's some limited [detail](http://smlnj.org/doc/features.html) on their implementation.

I stress that this is *not* a standard feature of SML, though.  It is not possible to achieve this directly using the SML module system.